# Should deleting a question cost the asker reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions

Sometimes we spend our time by answering a question and on submit we get *the question has been deleted* notification. It is always terrible.

What if the deletion costed 50/100/whatever reputation points?

Comment: 50-100 will be a bit extreme.

Comment: @Omeid Herat: may be. Reasonable value for me though.

Comment: This doesn't even make sense; you're trying to punish people who deleted a bad question because you happened to be in the middle of answering it?

Comment: @Michael: Based on the name of the question, he seems to be suggesting punishing people who *ask* a deleted question.

Comment: @Adrian Right, but I think he's assuming the asker deleted their own question, which is generally because they realized it's bad

Comment: Hehe, -8 ;-) My record

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't want to discourage people from deleting content that needs to be deleted.

Comment: What about having it peer deleted, which is possible?

Comment: Between down voting and flagging, I think we have enough punishment options. There are times when a question can be deleted that shouldn't warrant a rep hit.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the questions that get deleted by the OP in my experience are by low rep users (often simply 1 rep) who ask a question and then delete it.

Threatening them with losing rep doesn't sound like it would discourage them.

Still, I think there may be some option to reduce having a quality answer going to waste. What about a *This question has been deleted; do you want to [repost question with your answer](https://stackexchange.com/questions/repost/ac6f78bc8a)?* notification.

The link could then repost the question with the answerer as the owner, and their answer good to go. They could then edit the question and/or answer as they see fit, so the useful information and their time answering is not wasted.

Comment: You can't delete your own question if there are any upvoted answers - it's just not allowed.

Comment: @Joel Yeah I know that, but I've been half way through answering a question when the question is deleted.

Comment: that's why sometimes you have to FGITW the things ;)

Comment: Why don't you try that as a feature request rather than your original one.

Comment: @Wes What original one? My other feature request?

Answer (score 2):

Quite often, the question that are deleted are ones which have been down-voted. I think it will be just enough to keep the negative value in someones reputation, and remove the up-voted reputation for that question.